# Facebook auto-login

Tags: asp.net, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I have one situation. I create a website. Then I put a tab that will link to Facebook authorization login page. Can I pass login parameter(Email,Password) to the Facebook authorization login page?? So that the user can authorize the application without see the authorization login page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't do that. It would require the user to give you their facebook password which obviously would be breaking all kinds of terms and conditions. This is what OAuth is for. Check out the documentation on [authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication)

Comment: Thank you Abby. But all the login information(Email,Password) already store in the database and all the stored Facebook account are use for business purpose,not private purpose. Means that, all the posts are control by my website(example of post: 'Traffic are slow from south to north in highway XXX'). The situation is,I already put limitation where the Account can post to. For example,Account A can post only to FacebookPage A. Account B can post only to FacebookPage B. So all posting are filter by dropdown parameter....Hope you understand my explaination....

Comment: If i have understood correctly; by having the password to more than your own single personal facebook profile, you are breaking the facebook terms, regardless what you use them for. You cannot own more than one profile, you can't share passwords and you cant create profiles for imaginary people. It sounds like you are using the wrong tools for the job. What are you actually hopeing to achieve?

Comment: Thats right,its like I'm creating profile for imaginary people.....My website is create to be use by all Highway company in my country. Example of the company are LLM,LDP,KESAS,etc. So,I create(means I know all login information) new yahoo account, Facebook account and FacebookPage for each of the company. I name the Facebook account and page with the company name. So,if I login the website as LLM,the website will automatically login into Facebook as LLM. Then post to Facebook as LLM profile to LLM FacebookPage....Hope you get my situation Abby...

Comment: yeah, that isnt allowed as it breaks the facebook terms of use. You will need to rethink your implementation.